# How to use django-admin-sortable2 and django-import-export package together in admin panel?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-import-export

I want to use django-admin-sortable2 django-import-export package together in admin panel.
Here is the code:

```
class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, help_text="University or Institution Name")
    short_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=10, help_text="University or Institution 
 Short Name")
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        default=0,
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}-{self.name}' 

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order']
```

admin.py:

```
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

from adminsortable2.admin import SortableAdminMixin
# Register your models here.

class UniversityResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = University
        exclude = ('created_at', 'updated_at',)


class UniveresityAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, SortableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_classes = [UniversityResource]

admin.site.register(University, UniveresityAdmin)
```

**But this is not working**,
If I use:

```
class UniveresityAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, SortableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_classes = [UniversityResource]
```

Console:

```
failed to assign change_list_template attribute (see issue 1521)
```

This is the output:
[image]

If I use:

```
class UniveresityAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, SortableAdminMixin,):
```

This provides:
[image]
And if I use:

```
class UniveresityAdmin(SortableAdminMixin, ImportExportModelAdmin,):
```

This provides:

```
TypeError at /admin/core/university/
join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'list'
```

Both works single handed if I remove either one of them. But I want to use both package together.
**Is there any workaround to solve this issue?**
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you expand on what is not working?  Are you seeing any errors?  See this [thread](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/1531)

Comment: If I use class UniveresityAdmin( SortableAdminMixin, ImportExportModelAdmin,) then it occurs  TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'list' errror. And If I use UniveresityAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, SortableAdminMixin): then drag and drop option is not visible. Drag and drop and import-export both not visible  by using UniveresityAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin, SortableAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin). by this combination.

Comment: I have added the errors and result. Please check it.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that import-export and admin-sortable2 don't work together.  AFAIK there is no workaround.

The reason is that admin-sortable2 defines `change_list_template` as a property meaning it cannot be reset.  In import-export, all we can do is detect this and log the error:

> failed to assign change_list_template attribute (see issue 1521)

The link to this issue is [here](https://github.com/django-import-export/django-import-export/issues/1521).  There is an [open issue](https://github.com/jrief/django-admin-sortable2/issues/345) on admin-sortable2.